# Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to train custom relations in Stanford CoreNLP using the [birthplace model](http://cogcomp.org/Data/ER/m-birthplace.corp).

I have gone through this [documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html) which details us to make a properties file (similar to the roth.properties) as follows:

```
#Below are some basic options. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReadingProperties class for more options.

# Pipeline options
annotators = pos, lemma, parse
parse.maxlen = 100

# MachineReading properties. You need one class to read the dataset into correct format. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.ace.AceReader for another example.
datasetReaderClass = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothCONLL04Reader

#Data directory for training. The datasetReaderClass reads data from this path and makes corresponding sentences and annotations.
trainPath = "D:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\\birthplace.corp"

#Whether to crossValidate, that is evaluate, or just train.
crossValidate = false
kfold = 10

#Change this to true if you want to use CoreNLP pipeline generated NER tags. The default model generated with the relation extractor release uses the CoreNLP pipeline provided tags (option set to true).
trainUsePipelineNER=false

# where to save training sentences. uses the file if it exists, otherwise creates it.
serializedTrainingSentencesPath = "D:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\\rel\\sentences.ser"

serializedEntityExtractorPath = "D:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\\rel\\entity_model.ser"

# where to store the output of the extractor (sentence objects with relations generated by the model). This is what you will use as the model when using 'relation' annotator in the CoreNLP pipeline.
serializedRelationExtractorPath = "D:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\\rel\\roth_relation_model_pipeline.ser"

# uncomment to load a serialized model instead of retraining
# loadModel = true

#relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter,edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothResultsByRelation. For printing output of the model.
relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter

#In this domain, this is trivial since all the entities are given (or set using CoreNLP NER tagger).
entityClassifier = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothEntityExtractor

extractRelations = true
extractEvents = false

#We are setting the entities beforehand so the model does not learn how to extract entities etc.
extractEntities = false

#Opposite of crossValidate. 
trainOnly=true

# The set chosen by feature selection using RothCONLL04:
relationFeatures = arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path

# The above features plus the features used in Bjorne BioNLP09:
# relationFeatures = arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path,dependency_path_POS_unigrams,dependency_path_word_n_grams,dependency_path_POS_n_grams,dependency_path_edge_lowlevel_n_grams,dependency_path_edge-node-edge-grams_lowlevel,dependency_path_node-edge-node-grams_lowlevel,dependency_path_directed_bigrams,dependency_path_edge_unigrams,same_head,entity_counts
```

---

I am executing this command in my directory `D:\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09`:

```
D:\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\stanford-corenlp-3.8.0\edu\stanford\nlp>java -cp classpath edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading --arguments roth.properties
```

and I am getting this error

> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading
> ```

---

Also I have tried to programmatically train the custom relation model with the below C# code:

```
using java.util;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StanfordRelationDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jarRoot = @"D:\Stanford English Model\stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models\";
            string modelsDirectory = jarRoot + @"edu\stanford\nlp\models";
            string sutimeRules = modelsDirectory + @"\sutime\defs.sutime.txt,"
                              //+ modelsDirectory + @"\sutime\english.holidays.sutime.txt,"
                              + modelsDirectory + @"\sutime\english.sutime.txt";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "pos, lemma, parse");
            props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
            props.setProperty("datasetReaderClass", "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothCONLL04Reader");
            props.setProperty("trainPath", "D://Stanford English Model//stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models//edu//stanford//nlp//models//birthplace.corp");
            props.setProperty("crossValidate", "false");
            props.setProperty("kfold", "10");
            props.setProperty("trainOnly", "true");
            props.setProperty("trainUsePipelineNER", "true");
            props.setProperty("serializedTrainingSentencesPath", "D://Stanford English Model//stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models//edu//stanford//nlp//models//rel//sentences.ser");
            props.setProperty("serializedEntityExtractorPath", "D://Stanford English Model//stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models//edu//stanford//nlp//models//rel//entity_model.ser");
            props.setProperty("serializedRelationExtractorPath", "D://Stanford English Model//stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models//edu//stanford//nlp//models//rel//roth_relation_model_pipeline.ser");
            props.setProperty("relationResultsPrinters", "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter");
            props.setProperty("entityClassifier", "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothEntityExtractor");
            props.setProperty("extractRelations", "true");
            props.setProperty("extractEvents", "false");
            props.setProperty("extractEntities", "false");

            props.setProperty("trainOnly", "true");
            props.setProperty("relationFeatures", "arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path");

            var propertyKeys = props.keys();
            var propertyStringArray = new List<string>();
            while (propertyKeys.hasMoreElements())
            {
                var key = propertyKeys.nextElement();
                propertyStringArray.Add($"-{key}");
                propertyStringArray.Add(props.getProperty(key.ToString(), string.Empty));
            }

            var machineReader = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeMachineReading(propertyStringArray.ToArray());
            var utestResultList = machineReader.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this exception:

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>
> Unhandled Exception: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file) --->
> ```
>
> java.io.IOException: Unable to open
>   "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger"
>   as class path, filename or URL
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(String
>   textFileOrUrl)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(Properties
>   config, String modelFileOrUrl, Boolean printLoading)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(Properties
>   config, String modelFileOrUrl, Boolean printLoading)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger..ctor(String modelFile, Properties config, Boolean printLoading)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger..ctor(String modelFile)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(String ,
>   Boolean )
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator..ctor(String annotatorName, Properties props)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(Properties
>   properties)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$42(Properties
>   , AnnotatorImplementations )
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.**<>Anon4.apply(Object ,
>   Object )
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getDefaultAnnotatorPool$65(Entry
>   , Properties , AnnotatorImplementations )
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.**<>Anon27.get()
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.3.compute()
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get()
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(String name)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(Properties ,
>   Boolean , AnnotatorImplementations , AnnotatorPool )
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props, Boolean enforceRequirements, AnnotatorPool annotatorPool)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props, Boolean enforceRequirements)
>          at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeMachineReading(String[]
>   args)
>          at StanfordRelationDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\m1039332\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\StanfordRelationDemo\StanfordRelationDemo\Program.cs:line
>   46

---

**I am simply thus unable to train the custom relation using CoreNLP any obvious mistakes which I am making, I would appreciate if anybody would point it out.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the machine reading code is distributed with the standard distribution.

You should build a jar from the full GitHub.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/machinereading

Comment: is there a way to programmatically train the relations?